# While loop not responding

Tags: r

I have a small data set with a few columns like below,
what I wanted to do is use a "while loop" to let the size column
print "1,2,3,4,..." until the LotID is not the same with each other.

My code is as below:

```
for (i in nrow(Crystal.Diam.2)) {
  j <- 1
  while (identical(Crystal.Diam.2[i,1], Crystal.Diam.2[i-1,1])==TRUE) {
    j <- j+1
    Crystal.Diam.2[i,4]<- j
  }
}
```

The reason why I included "j" is I saw the example like:

```
i =1
while(i <=10){
print(i)
i=i+1
```

The above code would give me 1~11
so I wanted to try but failed.
Any helps would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
                        LotID Diameter SampleSize Size
    DPE.01789.P     RX1805570   14.265          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.1   RX1805570   14.232          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.2   RX1805570   14.224          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.3   RX1805570   14.244          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.4   RX1805570   14.231          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.5   RX1805570   14.255          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.6   RX1805570   14.248          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.7   RX1805570   14.254          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.8   RX1805570   14.246          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.9   RX1805570   14.258          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.10  RX1805570   14.261          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.11  RX1805570   14.239          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.12  RX1805570   14.244          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.13  RX1805570   14.245          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.14  RX1805570   14.264          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.15  RX1805570   14.234          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.16  RX1805570   14.243          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.17  RX1805570   14.259          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.18  RX1805570   14.253          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.19  RX1805570   14.241          1   NA
    DPE.01789.P.20  RX1805571   14.227          1   NA
```

Comment: Your while loop does not change the main variable `i` which is used for subsetting. Note that the logical statement is checking for identical values based on `i` not `j`, as such this one does not change at any point during the while loop. If it is true, it will stay true until `i` changes. As the while loop does not affect `i` this is forever.

Comment: My pleasure. :-)

Comment: But I wonder, do you have good suggestions on this question? I tried to use "group by" but it did not work. Thank you!!

Comment: I've added an answer to hopefully give you a viable suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is rather awkwardly phrased, making it unclear what is actually wanted.

But from the question it seems you want to make sequence column, `1,2,3,...` for each group by the `LotID` column. There are multiple ways to achieve this. First I'll 'try' to alter your own code, which will show how one can achieve 'a' solution with loops. Next I'll show how this can be achieved using the [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) package.

## Using loops

This is rather tricky, mostly just keeping track of what's what. It can be done using a single loop and some tracking variables. I suggest comparing it to your own code, as i fix some mistakes and point them out.

```
#Initiate the group
group <- NULL
#Note the 'seq' in the for
for(i in seq(nrow(Crystal.Diam.2))){
    if(group != Crystal.Diam.2[i, 1]){
        group <- Crystal.Diam.2[i, 1]
        j <- 1
    }
    Crystal.Diam.2[i, 4] <- j
}
```

`j` is used as a counter. I use the `if` statement to check if the group is the same, otherwise i reset the counter.

This could however also be achieved in a myriad other ways. One is `data.table` (another is tidyverse) as shown below

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Crystal.Diam.2)
#data table syntax. .N is the row count within grouping. Size := --- adds a column or assigns a column with the values on the RHS.
Crystal.Diam.2[, Size := seq(.N), by = LotID)
```

This is faster and more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, I solved this earlier but I just used "aggregate" to kinda grouping the LotID and that way I knew how much is the sample size for each LotID(as actually each LotID has different sample sizes and I did not want to manually counting that..). May I ask what if(group != Crystal.Diam.2[i, 1)){
group <- Crystal.Diam.2[i, 1] is going? Did it mean that you started a new group? So the "j" can follow how many groups we have, to iterate how many times?

Comment: My pleasure, the `if(group != Crystal.Diam.2[i, 1))...` is as you figured, a check of whether we are still counting the same group. Basically for each line, check if the group has changed, and if so, reset the counter.

Comment: is there typo for this command: Crystal.Diam.2[, Size := seq(.N), by = LotID)

Comment: That question is hard to answer. No, not from my side. I suggest checking the data table wiki page if it seems to bug out for you. It is linked at the first mention in my answer. :-)